# get only the data with a specific Id ,using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following table in database:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_client');
        $table->string('client',100);
        $table->string('adresse',255);
        $table->string('ville',100);
        $table->date('pays',100);
        $table->integer('id_filiale')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('actif')->default('1');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('id_filiale')->references('id_filiale')->on('filiales');
    });
}
```

And I want to display data into datatable, so I'm using the following function in my controller:

```php
public function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax()) {
        return datatables()
            ->of(Client::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id_client.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                $button .= ' <label  class="switch" >';
                $button .= '  <input type="checkbox" id="'.$data->id_client.'" class="switch selectRow" ';
                
                if ($data->actif == 1) {
                    $button .= "checked";
                }

                $button .= '><span class="slider round"></span></label>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';

                return $button;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    
    return view('Client.clients');
}
```

The problem is this method gets all the data stored in the table of database, but I want to get only the data with `id_filiale = 0` or `1`.

How can I add a condition to my function for getting only the clients with `id_filiale = 0 || id_filiale = 1`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datatable formatted data is fetched based on your Model Query

```php
Client::latest()->get()
```

So in order to filter this Client data that have `id_filiale = 0` or `1`, just add `whereIn()`.

For example:

```php
Client::whereIn('id_filiale', [0, 1])->latest()
```

Then just apply this query in the `->of()` method of your datatable:

```php
return datatables()->of(Client::whereIn('id_filiale', [0, 1])->latest())
...
```